# How to merge two columns of different data frame and if the match is found write "True" in a new column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on pandas project. I have two data frame similar to bellow

```
DF1 :

Data1    Data2      Data3
Head     Cat        Fire
Limbs    Dog        Snow
Eyes     Fish       Water
Mouth    Dragon     Air


DF2 :

 Data1     Data2      
 Limbs     Dog        
 Mouth     Dragon        
 Head      Cat
```

Based on the above Dataframe I need to compare both DF's and if the match is found I need to write "True" in a separate column else False

ex: lets say, I pick DF2 first row with combination (Limbs, Dog) this should be searched in DF1 , as we can see the combination exits in the 2nd row , then write DF1's Data3 value "Snow" to the DF2 Data3 value. and also print "True" value in a new column if the match is found.

**expected output**

```
Data1         Data2         Data3   Data4
 Limbs        Dog            Snow    True
 Mouth        Dragon         Air     True
 Head         cat            Fire    True
  Eyes         Fish         Water    False
```

Currently, I have tried merging two dataframe

Current Code :

```
df3 = pd.merge(df, valid_req , on=['Data1','Data2' ])

df3


 Data1         Data2         Data3  
     Limbs        Dog            Snow   
     Mouth        Dragon         Air     
     Head         cat            Fire
```

How can I achieve the expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and `indicator=True` parameter and then for new column compare by `both` with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for remove column:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['Data1', 'Data2'], how='left', indicator=True)
df['Data4'] = df.pop('_merge').eq('both')
print (df)
   Data1   Data2  Data3  Data4
0   Head     Cat   Fire   True
1  Limbs     Dog   Snow   True
2   Eyes    Fish  Water  False
3  Mouth  Dragon    Air   True
```

Comment: This seems to do the work ! , but lets say i have other columns also in the table how to retain them ? this code actually doesn't retain them

Comment: @Divakar - It should be, what columns are omitted? From first or from second dataframe?

Comment: @jezrael Great use of `indicator` arg. I didn't know that existed. So I provided a solution with `tmp` column. +1.

Comment: it worked with other columns too , this fix works perfectly!! , Thanks @jezrael and everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a temporary column to `df2` and then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) using `how='left'`:

```
In [1665]: df2['tmp'] = 1

In [1668]: x = df1.merge(df2, on=['Data1', 'Data2'], how='left')

In [1667]: x
Out[1667]: 
   Data1   Data2  Data3  tmp
0   Head     Cat   Fire  1.0
1  Limbs     Dog   Snow  1.0
2   Eyes    Fish  Water  NaN
3  Mouth  Dragon    Air  1.0
```

Finally, use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to assign the new column `Data4` based on if `x['tmp'] == 1` then `True`, else `False`:

```
In [1668]: import numpy as np

In [1669]: x['Data4'] = np.where(x.tmp.eq(1), True, False)
```

Drop the unnecessary `tmp` column using [`df.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html). **Then `x` is your final output**:

```
In [1671]: x.drop('tmp', 1, inplace=True)

In [1672]: x
Out[1672]: 
   Data1   Data2  Data3  Data4
0   Head     Cat   Fire   True
1  Limbs     Dog   Snow   True
2   Eyes    Fish  Water  False
3  Mouth  Dragon    Air   True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simply the apply function on DF1 to create the Data4:

```py
import pandas as pd

DF1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ["Head", "Cat", "Fire"],
    ["Limbs", "Dog", "Snow"],
    ["Eyes", "Fish", "Water"],
    ["Mouth", "Dragon", "Air"]
], columns=["Data1", "Data2", "Data3"])

DF2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ["Limbs", "Dog", "Snow"],
    ["Mouth", "Dragon", "Air"],
    ["Head", "Cat", "Fire"]
], columns=["Data1", "Data2", "Data3"])

DF1["Data4"] = DF1["Data1"].apply(lambda cell: DF2[DF2["Data1"]==cell]["Data1"].count()>0)
```